# Anything wrong with this plan for my model associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating an app that allows users to take multiple choice quizzes that I create.

There's a `Quiz` model, a `Question` Model, and an `Answer` model. The Quiz model `has_many` questions which `has_many` answers (and they all `belongs_to` the model intuitively above them).  `answers` will have a `correct_answer` boolean attribute that indicates ONE of the answers to be the correct answer. (and they all `belongs_to` the model intuitively above them). This is to create the quiz.

To provide support for user input once the quiz has already been created, I want to define two other models: `SubmittedAnswer` and `SubmittedQuiz`. `SubmittedSurvey` `belongs_to` User, and also `belongs_to` Quiz (both of which `has_many` `submittedsurveys`). `SubmittedQuiz` also `has_many` `submittedanswers`.

So when you visit the page that displays the quiz, it allows user input which submits data that sets `submittedanswers`. Then, since `submittedQUiz` `belongs_to` `Quiz`, I can compare `submittedanswers` to the `answers` themselves and grade the quiz. Is this reasonable or should I do it some other way?

Answer (score 1):

I think `SubmittedAnswer` should have a link (`belong_to :answer`) so that you can know which answer (and by relation which question) the user responded to.

Comment: right. If I do that then, do I even need a submittedquiz at all?

Comment: You probably do, only to make it easy to determine which Quizzes the user has attempted.